# how to transform '01 Oct 2015' into a valid date format, IF language = GERMAN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table, where date is coded in the form 'dd mmm yyyy', what normally should not be a problem, e.g. '01 **Oct** 2015'. BUT: As my system language is German, SQL-Server will not recognize it as date.

If I transform it to '01 **Okt** 2015' it's correctly read as date.

This means:

```
SELECT CONVERT (datetime, [Datum(Tag)], 106) AS Datum
```

does not work properly in this specific case.

How I have to proceed, to transform my data into a valid date format given the system language is german?

Comment: "what normally should not be a problem" - except all of the times that it will be, such as now. If you want to store a date, why aren't you using a datatype *designed* for holding date(time) data? E.g. `date`, `datetime2` or (for older versions) `datetime`?

Comment: This is exactly the problem. It does not work, when language is set to german.

Comment: No, the exact problem is, you're storing it as a *string*.

Comment: If I try to store it as date I get an error message. (conversion not possible)

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply change the language temporarily during the transformation?

```
SET Language German;

DECLARE @d NVARCHAR(100);
SELECT @d = '01 Okt 2015';

SELECT CONVERT (datetime, @d, 106) AS Datum

SET Language English;

SELECT @d = '01 Oct 2015';

SELECT CONVERT (datetime, @d, 106) AS Datum
```

This produces the same results in both cases on one of my test systems (SQL Server 2005).

Comment: As the data load is done via SSIS I don't know how to realize that at the moment.

Comment: I haven't found a solution up to now, but I found an abreviation for your script: SELECT PARSE (Datum AS date USING 'en-US') FROM dbo.TEST which does the same job without the need to SET language explicitly.

Comment: @Nylix Good point - that's an option from version SQL Server 2012 onwards (you didn't mention which version you use in your post, would be worth mentioning in future questions). Feel free to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

So, most of this has been covered in the comments, but I think it's worth repeating in the answer.

**First, identifying the actual problem:**
The problem is that the data is being stored in a string format when the data is a date type.  If it were stored as a date then this question wouldn't be necessary.

**Second, solving the issue:**
You've identified how to convert the string into a date, you should solve this before putting the data into the table to begin with (if possible).  If the load is happening in SSIS, then you can use a Data Conversion transformation to convert the data from a string into a date column.  Bing or Google "SSIS Data Conversion Transformation", this link worked for me:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/working-with-ssis-data-types/

**If you can't do that, consider a derived column**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.datetest ADD ActualDateDatum AS (PARSE (Datum AS date USING 'en-US'));
```